# Removing files from commit in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I have the following git pre-commit hook

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
make clean
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
```

However when I commit, the deleted files are unstaged.

And when I abort the commit, the files are gone from both the index and the working tree.

Is there a way to delete the files from the commit as well?